# How to set sate only after fetch is completed with all ids inside the object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to set the state after a fetch operation loop is completed(To display a loader until data is fetch is completed). I'm using an `async` function to do this by data.map but it is still running and my `setState` is happening prior to it. Any idea how to fix this, am I missing something here.

Here is my code:

```
class App extends Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { 

          posts: [],
          loading: true
        }
      }

      async componentDidMount() {
        await this.fetchNews();    
        this.setState({loading: false})

      }

      async fetchNews() {        
        await fetch('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/newstories.json')
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then((data) => {
            data.slice(0,10).map((newsId) => {
               fetch('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/' + newsId + '.json')
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then((itemDetail) => {
                  this.setState({ posts: [...this.state.posts, itemDetail] })
                  console.log('Fetching in progress');                  
                })
                return true;
            })
            console.log('done finished');
          })           
        }    
      render() {    
        var post = this.state.posts;
        const loading = this.state.loading;
        console.log(post)
        const listItems = post.map((link) =>
        <li key={link.id}>{link.title}</li> );

      return <div>
                  {loading ? <Loader type="MutatingDots" color="#somecolor" height={80} width={80} /> : <div>{listItems}</div>}        
        </div>;
     }    
}

export default App;
```

Here is my console log, you can see the done finished message getting printed at the beginning when the fetch is still running.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do **async operation inside map** use **Promise.all** and it will work just fine

```
const fetchNews = async () =>
  await fetch('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/newstories.json')
    .then((response: any) => response.json())
    .then(async (data: any) => {
      let news = data.slice(0, 10);
      await Promise.all(
        news.map(async (newsId: any) => {
          await fetch('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/' + newsId + '.json')
            .then((response: any) => response.json())
            .then((itemDetail: any) => {
               this.setState({ posts: [...this.state.posts, itemDetail] });
              console.log('Fetching in progress', newsId);
            });
          return true;
        })
      );
      console.log('done finished');
    });
```

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set state value inside the fetchnews function where you called console.log

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { 

      posts: [],
      loading: true
    }
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    await this.fetchNews();
  }

  async fetchNews() {

    await fetch('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/newstories.json')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        data.slice(0,10).map((newsId) => {
           fetch('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/' + newsId + '.json')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then((itemDetail) => {
              this.setState({ posts: [...this.state.posts, itemDetail] })
              console.log('Fetching in progress');


            })
            return true;
        })
        console.log('done finished');
        this.setState({loading: false})
      }) 

    }



  render() {

    var post = this.state.posts;
    const loading = this.state.loading;
    console.log(post)
    const listItems = post.map((link) =>
    <li key={link.id}>{link.title}</li> );

  return <div>
              {loading ? <Loader type="MutatingDots" color="#somecolor" height={80} width={80} /> : <div>{listItems}</div>}



    </div>;
  }

}

export default App;
```

Comment: No, I tried this before the Done finished console log is getting printed at the beginning after that arrays are still being fetched.

Comment: Added console log see image